# Get the IP Address of the device

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-tv, android-wireless

From inside my activity, I am trying to get the ip address of my device. I am using the following code to do this:

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But this function does not return me the correct ip address (possibly its returning the router ip and not the proxy ip given for my device). I went through lot of threads on StackOverflow but non of them helped.

Also, I dont plan to use :

```
WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
        int ipAddress = wifiInf.getIpAddress();
```

as in some cases my devices is wired connected and not wireless

Can someone suggest me how to get the correct ip address of my device from code?

Ideally, I would want that weather the device is wired/wireless connected, it should give the correct ip address of the device. In some situations, my device is wired connected.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: just as a reference http://itekblog.com/android-get-mobile-ip-address/

Comment: @matty357.. thanks for your comment. As you may see in my question that I used both the things suggested in your recommended link, but they don't solve my purpose for the reasons mentioned in question..